# Como selecionar arquivo da memória?

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando fazer um reprodutor de vídeo, mas não usando a "raw" ou da internet, preciso pegar o arquivo da memória do celular, seja memória interna ou memória sd card, já tentei através do caminho obtido por um "gerenciador de arquivos" mas quando coloco no Uri.parse do videoViewer, ele diz que não pode reproduzir o arquivo:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_pasta);
        VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Download/video.mp4"));
        video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    }
}
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia de como fazer?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta transformar nesse formato, que é para acesso a memória interna:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Download/video.mp4"))
```

ou

```
String filePath = getApplication().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                + File.separator + "video.mp4";
        File f = new File(filePath);
        if (f.exists()) {
            Uri internal = Uri.fromFile(f);
            video.setVideoURI(internal);
```

Para acessar arquivos no SDCARD você deve usar a função `getExternalStorageDirectory ()`, exemplo:

```
File files= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
```